# Apex webservice call calling site.createExternalUser giving That operation is only allowed from within an active site

Tags: user, provisioning

I have written an apex web service class that is going to be invoked by an external integration system. The purpose of this web service is to allow community user provisioning when being invoked.

We have a community site that already does self registration (user provisioning). However we also need to provide user provisioning to an external system therefore I have written the web service for this requirement.

When the web service is being invoked it is returning an error message

"USER_DEBUG [127]|DEBUG|ExternalUserCreateException:[displayMessages=(That operation is only allowed from within an active site.)]: [That operation is only allowed from within an active site.]"

The method inside the web service is:

```
private static boolean provisionedUser(String username, String contactId, 
                            String email, String firstName,
                            String lastName, String accountId, String password) {

    User u = new User();

    u.Username = username;
    u.ContactId = contactId;
    u.Email = email;
    u.FirstName = firstName;
    u.LastName = lastName;
    u.CommunityNickName = firstName + '.' + lastName + '.' + contactId;

    try {
        Site.createExternalUser(u, accountId, password);
        return true;
    } catch(Site.ExternalUserCreateException ex) {
        System.debug(ex);       
        return false;       
    }   

}
```

I believe this error is due to the context in which this web service is running in, due to not running in the community context.

My question is, is there a another way of achieving this ? Or am I just not doing it right.

Your response is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is because the end point URL invoked should   use active site URL.

The end point URL format will be sitedomain/services/apexrest.

Looks like the external system is invoking a wrong endpoint or using a site URL that's inactive.

Comment: I have just tried that and it now gives exception: 15:22:09:432 USER_DEBUG [127]|DEBUG|ExternalUserCreateException:[displayMessages=(You are already logged in.)]: [You are already logged in.]

Comment: You have to hit end point from external source with no session I'd..can you post which tool are you using for testing?

Comment: <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:zxp="http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/ExternalUserProvisionService">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <zxp:SessionHeader>
      </zxp:SessionHeader>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <zxp:isFirstTimeUser>
         <zxp:loginId>test@hotmail.com</zxp:loginId>
         <zxp:password>password123</zxp:password>
      </zxp:isFirstTimeUser>
   </soapenv:Body>

Comment: Yes I have taken session Id out as you can see from the request.

Comment: @Beatle you are using username and password already that's giving you session and hence error

Comment: http://forceguru.blogspot.in/2012/09/creating-public-web-service-in.html?m=1.   Use the above on how to call public service endpoint

Comment: the loginId and password are actually parameters to my web service.

Comment: got it :) .Whats your end point URL ?May not be exact but i want a sample to see if you are hitting it right

Comment: https://cs5.salesforce.com/services/Soap/class/ExternalService

Comment: thats not correct !!! It has to be your site URL there not your instance URL

Comment: Hi Mohith, you are absolutely correct, it was working after using the Site URL. Thank you so much for your help !

Comment: Please mark the answer as answered so that it helps others

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating user using this method `Site.createExternalUser(u, accountId, password);` Just insert user using simple DML. Create a contact first and then insert user using Contact Id.

Here is a code sample for your help.

```
--------------------- Customer Portal User created internally-----------------

Profile pf = [Select id,name from Profile where name ='Volunteer' limit 1];

account acc = [select name from accout where name="individual"];

Contact con = [select id,name,email,lastname,firstname,accoundid from contact where accountid=:accid limit 1];

User u2 = new User(contactId=con.Id, username=con.Email, firstname=con.FirstName,
lastname=con.LastName, email=con.Email,communityNickname = con.LastName + '_' + Rnd,
alias = string.valueof(con.FirstName.substring(0,1) + con.LastName.substring(0,1)), profileid = pf.Id, emailencodingkey='UTF-8',
languagelocalekey='en_US', localesidkey='en_US', timezonesidkey='America/Los_Angeles');
Database.DMLOptions dlo = new Database.DMLOptions();
dlo.EmailHeader.triggerUserEmail= true;
Database.saveresult sr = Database.insert(u2,dlo);
```